# замена иконки при прикреплении ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Где в коде надо прописать и что заменить, чтоб изменилась иконка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Нужно прописать в `head` страницы

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/path/to/img.png"/>
```

[Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters?locale=ru_RU)

Comment: спасибо большое!